# In Flutter: How can you detect when a touching finger has *entered* the widgets bounds?

Tags: flutter, gesture-recognition

It's quite a minimal question so I apologize but I haven't found any good tutorial on this.

In Flutter: How can you detect when a touching finger has *entered* the widgets bounds?

Comment: by using `GestureDetector` / `Listener` widgets, more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list) to check whether the widget you are touching is in the bounds or not.

By using this View Port Condition you can configure the view selection.

```
isInViewPortCondition : your condition
```